# Can somebody identify this Moentrol valve?

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

[image]

I want to replace the cartridge for this valve because pulling the handle to turn on the water has become more and more difficult.  I would like to figure out what cartridge I need to buy for this.  The house was built in 1954, and I suspect that the valve is as old as that.

I think that it might be this valve:

[3570](http://pro.moen.com/shared/docs/product-specifications/3570sp.pdf)

Also, what would the replacement cartridge be?  If it's is the 3570, then I guess I would need the [1225 cartridge](http://pro.moen.com/search/parts?search_scope=&search_terms=1225%20cardridge).

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just pull the cartridge out and take it to the hardware store with you?

Comment: While that sounds reasonable, what if they don't have the replacement part?  This valve belongs to the only shower in the house.

Comment: Then you put it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you have looks correct. It's very similar to the 3570 and that would require a 1225 cartridge.

However, I see that Lowe's (and probably most hardware stores) sells kind of a one size fits all cartridge by Moen for their older valves. The 1200E is most likely what you need.

***1200E* - Metal faucet - "Replaces single handle cartridges installed prior to 1990"**
http://www.lowes.com/pd_27473-866-1200E___?productId=4750863&pl=1&Ntt=moen+cartridge

***1225* - Plastic faucet - "Fits all Moen 1 handle faucets (excluding Posi-Temp and ExactTemp)"**
http://www.lowes.com/pd_27375-866-1225___?productId=3133585&pl=1&Ntt=moen+cartridge

If it doesn't fit, don't forget that you can always return it and try the other. My guess is the 1200E, but it's going to be one of these two.